# How to assemble two arrays with the assignment of elements into one. PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I break my head how to do this.I need to connect three data sets from different data tables. One ID has a key to the second, the second to the third (ID -> if UF_DRIVER has ID -> NAME1 or ID -> if UF_DRIVER has ID -> NAME2)

There are three arrays: `$arItems` and `$arProps1` and `$arProps2`

Elements of the first array `$arItems`:

```
Array([0] => 2707) Array([0] => 2708)
```

Elements of the second array `$arProps1`:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2707
            [UF_VISITOR] => 1909
            [UF_DRIVER] => 
        )
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2708
            [UF_VISITOR] =>
            [UF_DRIVER] => 1910
        )
)
```

Elements of the third array $arProps2:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1909
            [UF_FIRSTNAME] => NAME1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1910
            [UF_FIRSTNAME] => NAME2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2015
            [UF_FIRSTNAME] => NAME3
        )
)
```

How to merge these array elements into one array element ?:

```html
Array([0] => 2707 => Array(
                          [0] => Array(
                          
                          [ID] => 2707
                          [UF_VISITOR] => 1909
                          [UF_DRIVER] => 
                                       ) => Array ([0] => Array([ID] => 1909
                                                                [UF_FIRSTNAME] => NAME1
))

Array([0] => 2708 => Array(
                          [0] => Array(
                          
                          [ID] => 2708
                          [UF_VISITOR] =>
                          [UF_DRIVER] => 1910
                                       ) => Array ([0] => Array([ID] => 1910
                                                                [UF_FIRSTNAME] => NAME2
))
```

Comment: can you please post your expected output of array?

Comment: @KamleshSolanki I posted expected output of array. After "How to merge these array elements into one array element ?:"